Jinja: Include fields from context not in template
I'm working on a YAML template and want flexibility for scenarios where an unforeseen key/value pair is provided. For example, if I have the following (simplified) files:
# context_file.yaml passed as context when rendering
provided:
  my_key: my_value
  an_extra_key: some_value

# template.yaml.jinja
template_key: {{ provided["my_key" }}

the expected rendered output would be:
# rendered output
template_key: my_value

Is it possible to render any key/value pairs from the context that weren't accounted for in the template?
# desired rendered output
the_key: my_value # accounted for in template
an_extra_key: some_value # not in template originally, but want it rendered

